# How to make pgfplotstable read tables with macros

Tags: macros, pgfplotstable

I want to migrate my tables to pgfplotstables. I used to have a macro for the rows of my tables, partly, because Kile used to.

So currently, my tables more or less look like:

```
oldtable:
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
\myrow{}
\rowentry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
\end{tabular}
```

And I want to migrate that to something like:

```
newtable:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[debug]{
one & two & three\\
\myrow{}
\rowentry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
}
```

But that fails with the following error:

```
./main.tex:28: Package pgfplots Error: input table '<inline_table>' has an unba
lanced number of columns in row '1' (expected '3' cols; got '1'). Maybe the inp
ut table is corrupted? If you need unbalanced data, consider using 'nan' in emp
ty cells (perhaps combined with 'unbounded coords=jump').

------- PGFPLOTSTABLE DEBUG MODE: --------
./main.tex:28: Undefined control sequence.
\\  ->\let \reserved@e 
                       \relax \let \reserved@f \relax \@ifstar {\let \reserv...
l.28 }
```

I suppose that is because the macros don't get expanded.
I don't necessarily want to edit all the tables. So my question is: How to make pgfplotstables read my table definition?

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% global settings
\pgfplotstableset{
    col sep = &,
    row sep=\\,
    %string type, %% The error changes when enabling this type
}

\newcommand{\myrow}{foo & bar & baz\\}
\newcommand*{\rowentry}[6]{#1 & #2 & #3\\} %& #4}\\}
\begin{document}

oldtable:
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
\myrow{}
\rowentry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
\end{tabular}

newtable:
\pgfplotstabletypeset[debug]{
one & two & three\\
\myrow{}
\rowentry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

% global settings
\pgfplotstableset{
    col sep = &,
    row sep=\\,
    string type, %% The error changes when enabling this type
}

\newcommand{\myrow}{foo & bar & baz\\}
\newcommand*{\rowentry}[6]{#1 & #2 & #3\\} %& #4}\\}

\def\foo#1[#2]#3{{
\let\\\relax
\gdef\tmpa{#1[#2]}%
\xdef\tmpb{\noexpand\tmpa{#3}}}%
\tmpb}

\begin{document}

oldtable:
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
1&2&3\\
\myrow{}
\rowentry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
\end{tabular}

\foo
\pgfplotstabletypeset[debug]{
one & two & three\\
\myrow{}
\rowentry{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}{6}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You, sir, are awesome. Thanks. It works with the small caveat of one having to provide the optional argument. But that's fine. It looks much like dark magic to me and I am afraid I would have been able to come up with that myself. Can you explain a little what it does, if it's not too much to ask for?

Comment: It could be re-arranged to not requote the argument or you could have to functions `\def\foob#1#2{{
\let\\\relax
\gdef\tmpa{#1}%
\xdef\tmpb{\noexpand\tmpa{#2}}}%
\tmpb}` to use in the no `[]` case. It simply uses `\xdef` to expand any macros in the main argument of `\pgfplotstabletypeset` _before_ `\pgfplotstabletypeset` is called, so the pgf code never sees \`myrow` or `\rowentry`, the `string type` that you had added but commented out is then needed as teh pgf code then _does_ see `foo & bar & baz` which are not numbers:-)